# Console doesn't write any value

Tags: c#, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape `books.toscrape.com` everything seems perfect, but it doesn't output anything to console.

I'm sure about the XPaths are correct, and syntax is right.

I don't see any errors, or warnings.

Don't have any clue what i can try for this problem.

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using System.Data;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace book_scraping
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {



        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        string user_url;
        class Book
        {

            public string Titlex { get; set; }
            public string Price { get; set; }
            public string Rate { get; set; }


        }


        public void Scrape()
        {
            var books = new List<Book>();
            IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            user_url = Textbox1.Text;
            int.TryParse(Textbox2.Text, out var x);
            for (int i = 1; i < x; i++)
            {
                driver.Url = "http://" + user_url + "/catalogue/" + "page-" + i + ".html";
                var element = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//article[@class='product_pod']"));
                foreach (var elements in element) {

                    var book = new Book
                    {
                        Titlex = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//h3/a")).Text,
                        Price = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//p[@class='price_color']")).Text,
                        Rate = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//article/p")).GetAttribute("class")?.Replace("star-rating ", ""),
                    
                    };
                    foreach (var a in books)
                    {

                        Console.WriteLine($"{a.Titlex} {a.Price} {a.Rate}");

                   }

                }


            }

        }
    

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Scrape();

        }


    }

}
```

I expect the output of title,price,rate as text like
hello world 50 three, or something similar

Comment: this doesn't look like it's a console application.

Comment: But when do you ever `.Add()` to the `books` list? It's declared but not used.

Comment: You're not adding any book to `books`... Also your third loop probably needs moved outside as well...otherwise there's no reason to create a list that you will loop through just to print out to the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Books list is empty, try this

```cs
books.Add(new Book
{
   Titlex = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//h3/a")).Text,
   Price = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//p[@class='price_color']")).Text,
   Rate = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//article/p")).GetAttribute("class")?.Replace("star-rating ", ""),

});
```

instead of:

```cs
var book = new Book
{
   Titlex = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//h3/a")).Text,
   Price = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//p[@class='price_color']")).Text,
   Rate = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//article/p")).GetAttribute("class")?.Replace("star-rating ", ""),

};
```